# SharePoint 2013 REST api to update list item- Uncaught ReferenceError: etag is not defined

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, ajax, rest

I try to update my sharepoint list using REST api. But following code throws exception in browser "Uncaught ReferenceError: etag is not defined "
Can someone help to resolve this issue?

```
 // update an item 
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle(\'Suppliers\')/items(1)';
    var requestHeaders = { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 
        'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(), 
        'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE', 
        'If-Match': etag }; 
    var customerData = { __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.ContactsListItem' }, Title: 'NewName', }; 
    requestBody = JSON.stringify(customerData); 
    $.ajax({ url: requestUri, type: 'POST', 
        contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose', headers: requestHeaders, 
        data: JSON.stringify(customerData)
    ,
    success: function (response)
    { alert('Success');
    }, 
    error: function(error)
    { 
        alert('error');
    } 
    });
```

Comment: try "IF-MATCH": "*"

Comment: It may help to show where you specify your variable `etag`.

Comment: @Aanchal  Now, 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)'. But URL is working fine.

Comment: When I try to run the sample, I get the following in Google Chrome's developer tools, console window:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://XXX:1000/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle(\'Suppliers\')/items(1).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This error occurs since `tag` variable is not defined.

### About eTag

> When updating or deleting items within SharePoint lists via REST you
>   must specify the Entity Tag (eTag) value that was returned with the
>   item during the initial query. This enables SharePoint to determine if
>   the item has changed since it was requested. Alternatively you can
>   tell SharePoint to perform the operation regardless by specifying * as
>   the eTag value. For example:
>
> - `If-Match`: item.__metadata.etag can be used to specify the actual    eTag value (‘item’ is the object returned from SharePoint containing
>     the list item in JSON format).
> - `If-Match`: `*` can be used to match any eTag value resulting in the    operation being performed regardless of the actual value.

### How to update List Item via SharePoint REST interface

```
function updateJson(endpointUri,payload, success, error) 
{
    $.ajax({       
       url: endpointUri,   
       type: "POST",   
       data: JSON.stringify(payload),
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: { 
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest" : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
          "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
           "If-Match": "*"
       },   
       success: success,
       error: error
    });
}

function getItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return"SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) + "ListItem";
}

function updateListItem(webUrl,listTitle,listItemId,itemProperties,success,failure)
{
     var listItemUri =  webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")";
     var itemPayload = {
       '__metadata': {'type': getItemTypeForListName(listTitle)}
     };
     for(var prop in itemProperties){
           itemPayload[prop] = itemProperties[prop];
     }
     updateJson(listItemUri,itemPayload,success,failure);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var itemProperties = {'Title':'John Doe'};
updateListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Contacts',1,itemProperties,printInfo,logError);
function printInfo()
{
    console.log('Item has been created');
}
function logError(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

### References

[Manipulating list items in SharePoint Hosted Apps using the REST API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/02/22/manipulating-list-items-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-the-rest-api.aspx)

Comment: Good explanation about Manipulating list items in SharePoint using the REST API. Thanks @Vadim

Comment: hello I am getting 204 response code.why can you please tell me?its updated item successfully but why not give 200 response code. i am passing etag " * " in header and method merge then why i get this response code ?? how to resolve this. its show no content but what exact mean of it what i am doing wrong

Comment: eeeehm the `getItemTypeForListName(name)` function does not return the correct format for a custom List.