# Updating List Item using REST API generates no error but nothing happend

Tags: 2013, rest, updatelistitems, item

Following is my code using Rest API to update a List Item. It generates no error, goes to success callback. However it does not update the List Item.

```
var itemTitle = "Test item";
var userId = 22; //it is true the user exists
var now = new Date();
var date = now.getDate() + "/" + now.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + now.getFullYear();
var time = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
var newMessage = "<u>" + currentUserName + " <u>changed: " + date + " " + time + "</u><br/>-----------------------<br/>";

var listItemUri = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items?$filter=Title eq '" + itemTitle + "'";

var properties = {
      '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.MyListListItem" }, //checked this is right
       "Title": itemTitle,
       "MyUser": userId,
        "Last_x0020_Updated": now,
        "MyMessage": newMessage
   };

    $.ajax({
       url: listItemUri,
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       data: JSON.stringify(properties),
       headers: {
           "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));
             alert("updated");
         },
         error: function (data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
            alert("Failed");
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try URL

```
webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('LoggingList')/items(1)"
```

Where 1 is the ID of item to update

Comment: Does it mean it will update all items?

Comment: No for updating you need to specify which item. See my edit

Comment: the problem is I don't know the id of the item, I know the title

Comment: Ok then you need to make two calls.. First `GET` item using filter, find the `ID` and then use `POST` to update

Comment: so it doesn't enough to get the item using filter and title?

Comment: No for updating you need to target list item.. Filter works only with retrieving items

Comment: I Get the id and changed as you said, now It returns this:{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetById."}}}

Comment: For update you don't need `__meta..`.. Check this post for proper post data http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115950/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-to-update-list-item-uncaught-referenceerror-etag-is-n

Comment: I already marked your answer as right aswer. I have one more question why when it comes back to success callback the data is undefined?

Comment: Its POST request... For data you need to get request to a URL which returns data..