# REST interface payload for Project Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, project-server

I am trying to update some properties of an object using the REST interface.

I am able to read the information with the GET request, but when I'm PATCH-ing (MERGE-ing) I always get a 403 Forbidden error.

I am totally new to the REST interface, and frankly, I didn't find any information or example regarding a project server payload or any example for that matter.

This is how the JSON data looks when I GET it from the server:

```
{
  -d: {
      -__metadata: {
        .........
       }
       ActualFinish:0001-01-01T00:00:00
       ActualOvertime: null
       ...
       PercentComplete: 0 (this is what I want to change to 100)
       ...
      }
}
```

This is how my payload looks right now:

```
{d:PercentComplete=100}
```

It's not working. How the normal payload should look? Do I need any additional headers, other than the

```
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
```

As I said, I didn't find an example for these kind of updates.

Answer (score 1):

You need three additional headers:

1. `"X-RequestDigest":"value"` 
   A unique security token to validate your requests.
2. `"X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"` 
   To indicate that you're performing an update
3. `"If-Match":*` 
   To handle concurrent requests. This actually has 2 values viz. `item.__metadata.etag` representing the actual item tag and `*` to handle any value.

As an example refer to this excellent answer by Vadim: [SharePoint 2013 REST api to update list item- Uncaught ReferenceError: etag is not defined](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115950/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-to-update-list-item-uncaught-referenceerror-etag-is-n)