# Sharepoint Online : Rest API POST method getting - 415 (Unsupported Media Type) OR 400 (Bad request)

Tags: javascript, rest, ajax, updatelistitems

Im new on SharePoint online and i want "POST" (update my list) with Ajax

First step :

```
var listName = "Creation de projet";
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var itemId = "18"; // Update Item Id here
var title = "New Updated Title";
updateListItem(itemId, listName, url, title, function () {
    alert("Item updated, refreshing avilable items");
}, function () {
    alert("Ooops, an error occured. Please try again");
});
```

Second step:

```
function updateListItem(itemId, listName, siteUrl, title, success, failure) {

var test = GetItemTypeForListName('Creation_x0020_de_x0020_projet');
var itemType = "SP.Data.Creation_x0020_de_x0020_projetListItem";
var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": test },
    "Title": title
};

    getListItemWithId(itemId, listName, siteUrl, function (data) {

        $.ajax({
          url: data.__metadata.uri,
          type: "POST",
          data: JSON.stringify(item),
          headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",                
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
              "If-Match": "*"
          },
          success: function (data) {
              success(data);
          },
          error: function (data) {
              failure(data);
          }
    });
    }, function (data) {
        failure(data);
    });
}

function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}

function getListItemWithId(itemId, listName, siteurl, success, failure) {

    var url = siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$filter=Id eq " + itemId;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.results.length == 1) {
                console.log("DATA ITEM", data);
                success(data.d.results[0]);
            }
            else {
                failure("Multiple results obtained for the specified Id value");
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

And the answer getListItemWithId :

[image]
Thanx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely getting an error because you are not supplying the correct 
`listitementitytypefullname`.

To check that value , you need to query the below url:

```
/_api/lists/getbytitle('Creation de projet')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

After that in your second step, replace it as:

```
var itemType = "SP.Data.Creation_x0020_de_x0020_projetListItem";
```

Also i have changed the eTag.

Related discussion - [Vadim's excellent answer - SharePoint 2013 REST api to update list item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115950/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-to-update-list-item-uncaught-referenceerror-etag-is-n)

So try your code as below:

**First step:**

```
var listName = "Creation de projet";
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var itemId = "18"; // Update Item Id here
var title = "New Updated Title";

updateListItem(id);
```

**Second step**

```
var itemType = "SP.Data.Creation_x0020_de_x0020_projetListItem";
var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
    "Title": "updated title" //change as necessary, just for test purposes
};

function updateListItem(id){

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Creation de projet')/items(" + listItemId + ")",
        type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(item),
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",                
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": "*"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Now i have 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: sorry my bad, can you check edited code ?

Comment: yes and add a screen ! thx

Comment: no sadly :s i dont know why

Comment: Have edited and tested the code, can you check again ? I dont know what is there in the `getlistitemwithid` method, but i dont think its necessary if you already know the id.

Comment: i don't understand the url on ajax POST url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Creation de projet')/items(" + listItemId + ")", << listItemId  ??

Comment: it's working !!! thx mannn