# Error 415 (uns. media type) when creating new item list on SP Online using REST API and POSTMAN

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, content-type, sharepoint-rest-api, postman

As you can see I'm successfully authenticated to my tenant as I can retreive the List info.

[image]

But I just can't create an item. I always get an 415 error "Usupported media type" whatever the headers I tried eg:

```
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose 
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose 
X-HTTP-Method: POST 
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL...
```

Here is the Body of the request:

```
data:{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.OiseNumListItem"},"Operateur":"opérateur","typeEquipement":"Poteau","accesDifficile":"Oui","adresse":"mon adresse","codePostal":"38100","Commune":"Grenoble","natureDeclarant":"Particulier","nomDeclarant":"Julien","emailDeclarant":"julien@gmail.com","Photo1":"blablabla.jpg photo1"}
```

[image: And the result in POSTMAN]

With a GET the answer is even weirder as I get a status OK with an empty body and nothing added to the list

[image]

What's wrong?

thx

Comment: please share your code, so that we can have a look at it and tell you where you are going wrong.

Comment: Have a look at this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/207700/sharepoint-online-rest-api-post-method-getting-415-unsupported-media-type

Comment: Thx Karthik but this is a REST API so this should work using plain HTTP with a test software like POSTMAN no code needed here